# I've set firebase Session Length to be 1 minute and need my angular 2 code to redirect the user when the auth token expires

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular

I've set Firebase Session Length to be 1 minute and need my angular 2 code to redirect the user when the auth token expires.

Currently when the auth token naturally expires and your logged in it shows a yellow console message.

I would like to know how to listen to this signal in my angular 2 code and then redirect them to homepage.

I'm using angular 2, typescript and firebase for this.

Thank you

Comment: See [monitoring auth state](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try the `onAuth` function:

> Listens for changes to the client's authentication state.
>
> A callback that fires when the client's authenticate state changes. If authenticated, the callback will be passed an object containing the fields uid (the unique user id), provider (string identifying the provider), auth (the auth. token payload), and expires (expiration time in seconds since the Unix epoch) - and more, depending upon the provider used to authenticate. Otherwise, null.

Here is a sample of use:

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
  ref.onAuth((authData) => {
    if (!authData) {
      console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
      this.router.navigate(['LogginPage']);
    }
  });
}
```

See this page in the API documentation of the Firebase JavaScript client:

- https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Do you know if theres a listener, so that when firebase fires with your not authenticated my code would run. A bit like signalR

Comment: Yes, you provide a listener to the `onAuth` method (here defined as an arrow function). When you authentication expires, this callback is called...

Comment: Hi I've got it working using your code. Only problem I have is, when console.log("Client unauthenticated.") fires the routes are all undefined so I cant redirect. Where would you put this code in order for it to know the routes so I can redirect the user to the homepage

Comment: Cool! You mean the `router` parameter is null in the constructor?

Comment: Yeh, it says undefined. I try to navigate to home But I get this console error: 

Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Comment: Do you specify `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` in the second parameter when calling the `bootstrap` function?

Comment: So where you've got " this.router.navigate(['LogginPage']);" would fail as the this.router is undefined

Comment: Yeh I do and I currently have your code in my constructor in my app.ts file

Comment: This is my app.ts bootstrap: bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService, SocialService, UserService, EmailService, OrganisationService, NotificationService, ANGULAR2_GOOGLE_MAPS_PROVIDERS]);

Comment: I think that the component where you try to use `router` must be involved in routing. I mean within a component (or a sub component of) having `@RouteConfig`...

Comment: I've got it working now. I just did it on subscribe router change and checked if auth then rather than wait for the trigger. so now when router changes it checks then logs them out